# Не виден баннер AdMob (onFailedToReceiveAd)

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте уважаемые!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после подключения adMob в приложение не виден баннер, а LogCat выдает сообщение:onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.), т.е. как я понял запрос отсылается, но не принимается (хотя могу ошибаться)

Все делал по статье с хабра [Монетизация Android-приложения](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/133858/)

Так же проверил пример из статьи - такая же проблема. В проекте использую для теста AVD c SDK 2.1, а также телефон с Android 2.1 update 1. Версия библиотеки GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1. Изначально проект писался под Android 2.1, но в статье требовалось перейти на 3.2, что и было сделано(minSdkVersion остался 7).   Если нужна еще какая-нибудь информация спрашивайте...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

короче как я понял, ошибка из-за маленьких размером окошка в которое ты пробудешь засунуть эту рекламу, удали, если есть, padding и margins

**UPD.1**

> Ad request successful, but no ad
> returned due to lack of ad inventory.

хотя тут сказано, что запрос успешный, но данные не вернулись изза их отсутствия, может просто не приходят на эмулятор из-за невозможности определения твоей локали

Comment: В статье на это сделан акцент, так что все пермишины описаны. Интернет соединение проверял, все работает (кроме adMob конечно).

Comment: Убрал паддинги и т.д., таже ошибка. Я проверял пример из статьи от тоже не работает, там нет никаких паддингов и т.д и по идее должно все работать. Вы пробовали данный пример загрузить и запустить? (т.е. работает ли он у Вас)

Comment: нет, я пробовал погуглить такие же проблемы на стеке...

Comment: В общем начал тестировать на реальном телефоне, спустя где-то мин 40 начала появляться реклама... Возможно проблема была именно в локале, хотя и не уверен. В общем отмечаю ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Такое бывает если нет рекламы в Вашем регионе, пробуйте в тестовом режиме для надежности
запускать банер.